# How to allow a service listening and accepting sockets on a port using custom selinux policy?

Tags: centos7, selinux

I'm implementing a custom selinux policy (targeted) for a more or less typical systemd managed service `(prometheus node_exporter)`. I've utilized `"ausearch"` in order to get all permissions which the service needs to function.

But when I call `"curl localhost:9100/metrics"` the response is "connection reset by peer". It turned out that this is caused by a missing permission. In order to get it working I had to add following rule in addition to those from `"ausearch":`

allow `node_exporter_t self:tcp_socket create_stream_socket_perms;`

Whole .te file:

```
policy_module(node_exporter, 1.0.0)

type node_exporter_t;
type node_exporter_exec_t;
init_daemon_domain(node_exporter_t, node_exporter_exec_t)

type node_exporter_unit_t;
systemd_unit_file(node_exporter_unit_t)


allow node_exporter_t self:tcp_socket { accept bind create getattr listen setopt };

### Not working without this rule:
allow node_exporter_t self:tcp_socket create_stream_socket_perms;
###

corenet_tcp_bind_generic_node(node_exporter_t)
corenet_tcp_bind_hplip_port(node_exporter_t)
dev_list_sysfs(node_exporter_t)
dev_read_sysfs(node_exporter_t)
fs_getattr_tmpfs(node_exporter_t)
fs_getattr_xattr_fs(node_exporter_t)
init_read_state(node_exporter_t)
kernel_read_fs_sysctls(node_exporter_t)
kernel_read_net_sysctls(node_exporter_t)
kernel_read_network_state(node_exporter_t)
kernel_read_rpc_sysctls(node_exporter_t)
kernel_read_software_raid_state(node_exporter_t)
kernel_read_system_state(node_exporter_t)
kernel_search_network_sysctl(node_exporter_t)
```

I haven't found an explanation why I need this additional rule yet. Does someone know whats going on here?

Actually I would assume that these particular rules should be enough...

- `corenet_tcp_bind_generic_node(node_exporter_t)`
- `corenet_tcp_bind_hplip_port(node_exporter_t) **<- port 9100 is labled as hplip**`
- allow `node_exporter_t self:tcp_socket { accept bind create getattr listen setopt };`

Answer (score 2):

OK it took me a long time to come across the "dontaudit" feature of selinux.

So in order to get all necessary permissions you can follow this procedure:

```sh
# Disable "dontaudit"
semodule -DB

#
# Do your stuff that creates permission violations
# 

# Grab needed rules
ausearch -m avc --raw | audit2allow -R

#enable "dontaudit" back again
semodule -B
```